# Chartjs Custom Legend with Time on Y-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am creating a very simple chart with chart.js and stuck with the two small issues.

Below is the code that I am using to create the chart/graph

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
 <canvas name="myChart" id="myChart" width="400px" height="400px"> </canvas>
 </div>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
animation: false,
data: {
    labels: ["Service A", "Service B", "Service C"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Time In Service',
        data: [180, 360, 180],
        backgroundColor: [
            '#0073CF',
            '#FF0000',
            '#7DC24B'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            '#fff',
            '#fff',
            '#fff'
        ],
        borderWidth: 2 
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
```

The current chart can be seen here [Chart Generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d26l.jpg)
What is Need is something like [Chart Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kC1l.jpg)

1. I want the x-axis labels in legend on right side
2. Currently the time is in seconds in data. I want to Show time spend on x-axis in hours:min

Any little help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a try like this,

Need to modify your data structure a little and set the y=axis properties for displaying the required label format.

P.S : you need to use the latest chart.js library since the position right functionality was recently added and also i have increased the second value in your given example to display some meaningful data in hh:mm format.

```js
function formatTime(secs)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
   
    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);
 
    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);
  
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");


var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
animation: false,
data: {
    labels: ["Time"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Service A", 
        data: [1800], 
        backgroundColor: '#0073CF',
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 2 
    },
    {
        label: "Service B",
        data: [36000],
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 2 
    },
    {
        label: "Service C",
        data: [8000],
        backgroundColor: '#7DC24B',
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 2 
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true,
                callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                 return formatTime(label);
                 }
            }
        }]
    },
    legend: {
            position: "right",
            display:true
      
        }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
 <canvas name="myChart" id="myChart" width="400px" height="400px"> </canvas>
 </div>
```

Comment: that solve  the problem. Thanks a bunch.  Can we add css to legend?

Comment: you can assign some options like font color font size. check here https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/02-Scales.md#ticks-configuration